# How to correctly make install of binaries and data after compile in linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, installation

After make of sources I have compiled executable file and data directory with images for it. What should I do at "make install" phase to correctly install these files to the linux system? And how then application can find installed data (in case when binary and data are placed in different directories)?

Are there any standards for this?

Comment: The "standard" for installing packages on Linux systems is to use prepared packages from safe sources, so from the configured repositories and install those via the software management. For a "wild" installation as you perform it there are only conventions. What exactly happens when you execute a "make install" is defined in the Makefile being part of the sources. Only you can look into, since we don't know what package you are trying to install. But in general it uses the `cp` command and a few similar things to move files to where they should go. So _check your Makefile!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to install packages on a Linux and Unix system much like any other operating system. The normal method of installing software is through your distributions package manager. Package managers are different based on the distribution you are using but in general they take a package (a file filled with binaries source code or other files required for the piece of software to work) and place it into the corresponding places as defined by the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). When you do a `make install` what you are doing is bypassing the package manager and placing the binaries into the hierarchy standard directly making it nearly impossible for the package manager to handle or account for that programs existence. This is not a good thing for anyone as it is hard to keep a system secure or stable with many unknown files placed throughout the system. Please if you want to install something manually please take a look at the filesystem hierarchy stabdard and place the files under the appropriate folder in either /opt and create a symlink in an area covered by your PATH variable or under /usr/local/

Comment: If the makefiles are written correctly, "make install" will already try to install to "/usr/local"  by default, which was created specifically to avoid this problem.